# Multiplying an integer and a decimal in a Django model using model expressions

Tags: django, django-models, query-expressions

I am a Django beginner and in one of my projects, I made this model:

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coil = models.ForeignKey(Cut_Material ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    piece_length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    prime_pieces = models.IntegerField()
    reject_pieces = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.piece_length))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-order","piece_length"]
```

I want to multiply `piece_length` with `prime_pieces` to get running meters and here are  my solutions:

**Solution 1:**

**Solution**: `Piece.objects.annotate(running_meters = (F('piece_length') * F('prime_pieces')))`

**Error**:`TypeError: QuerySet.aggregate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.FloatField>.`

**Solution 2**

**Solution**: `Piece.objects.annotate(running_meters = (F('piece_length') * F('prime_pieces')), output_field=FloatField())`

**Error**: `TypeError: QuerySet.aggregate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.FloatField>.`

Can anyone help me with a solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

By uising:

> ```
> Piece.objects.annotate(
>     running_meters = (F('piece_length') * F('prime_pieces')),
>     output_field=FloatField()
> )
> ```

(formatting added), you simply try to make an extra annotation `output_field` which maps to a `FloatField`.

What you need here is an [**`ExpressionWrapper`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions), and `output_field=…` is a *parameter* of `ExpressionWrapper`:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper

Piece.objects.annotate(
    running_meters=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('piece_length') * F('prime_pieces'),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```